# Changing the UINavigationBar background image without restarting app

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Right now, I have

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"UINavigationBarBackground.png"] 
           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I want it to change the background on-click. Right now, it only changes after you restart the app. Is there a way to have it change the background image of the navigation bar without having to restart the app?

I tried

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setNeedsDisplay];
```

but it crashes with: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSMethodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:]: index (2) out of bounds [0, 1]'

And if I try

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
```

or

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationBar is just another (but slightly special) subclassed UIView that Apple provides in iOS, so you should be able to force an update using something like ["`setNeedsDisplay`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) right after you adjust the image.