# How Properly To Set Font for All Labels in View Controller Using UIAppearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uiappearance

I am trying to set the font of labels in the whole app (or at least labels controlled by View Controller) the same, therefore, I chose the option of creating category like it is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app) or [here](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-8-using-uiappearance-for-a-custom-look/). For these purposes I created the method "setSubstituteFont" in the UILabel category. However, the syntax

```
[[UILabel appearance] setSubstituteFont];
```

gives me always the same error if I put that statement in my View Controller:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSMethodSignature
>   getArgumentTypeAtIndex:]: index (2) out of bounds [0, 1]'

I prefer to implement that feature in my View Controllers since my Views are .xib, therefore, the recomendations to use "setNeedsDisplay" as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121218/changing-the-uinavigationbar-background-image-without-restarting-app) are not an option.

I also tried other options like:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIViewController class], nil] setSubstituteFont];
```

or

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[self class], nil] setSubstituteFont];
```

or

```
[[UILabel appearanceForTraitCollection:self.traitCollection] setSubstituteFont];
```

since "appearanceWhenContainedIn" is deprecated in iOS9 according [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceForTraitCollection:) but still getting the same error, and the app is crashed.

Between, "setSubstituteFont" method looks like that:

```
- (void)setSubstituteFont UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR {
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Book" size:54.0];
}
```

The used selector was taken from [the list](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@interface UILabel (UIAPP)
- (void)setSubstituteFont:(UIFont *)font UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@end


@implementation UILabel (UIAPP)
- (void)setSubstituteFont:(UIFont *)font {
    if (font == nil) {
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Book" size:54.0];
    } else {
        self.font = font;
    }
}
@end
```

Call where you need even in View Controller:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setSubstituteFont: nil];
```